# Building a client side transfer method for p:pickList

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working with Mojarra JSF 2.1.28 and Primefaces 3.5. I want to implement a client-side transferring input for the [`p:pickList`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf) component, where the user types something and the value is searched through the labels at the list of available elements, then it's transferred to the target list. That's how my code looks like:

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <script>
        //Just for testing, transfer the second element 
        //to the target list when document is ready. Works well
        $(document).ready(function(string) {
            transfer("name2");
        });
        //Transfer function. It takes each list item from the source list and checks if it matches with the given pattern
        //If it does, moves it to the target list
        function transfer(string) {
            $(".ui-picklist-source li").each(function() {
                var re = new RegExp(string);
                if ($(this).attr('data-item-label').match(re)) {
                    $(".ui-picklist-target").append($(this));
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
    <h:form>
        <p:inputText
            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { transfer(this.value); return false;}" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:pickList value="#{bean.elements}" var="element"
            itemLabel="#{element.name}" itemValue="#{element.name}" id="picklist" />
        <p:commandButton value="Send" action="#{bean.send}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable{

    public class Element {

        private String name;

        public Element(String n) {
            name = n;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Element [name=" + name + "]";
        }

    }

    private DualListModel<Element> elements;

    public Bean() {
        List<Element> source = new ArrayList<Bean.Element>();
        List<Element> target = new ArrayList<Bean.Element>();
        source.add(new Element("name1"));
        source.add(new Element("name2"));
        elements = new DualListModel<Bean.Element>(source, target);
    }

    public DualListModel<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void send() {
        System.out.println("Available: " + elements.getSource() + " assigned: "
                + elements.getTarget());
    }

    public void setElements(DualListModel<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

}
```

Well, in this test case, there are two items to play with, `name1` and `name2`. When page loads, I use [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to call my `transfer(string)` function in order to move `name2` to the target list. Page gets properly loaded and if we click on `Send` button, we get the second element properly assigned.

Problem comes when calling the function using the `p:inputText` component. Here, we listen to the Enter key event to send the current given value and perform a transfer. At client side it works fair enough, it behaves as expected. However, when clicking on `Send`, model doesn't get properly updated at server side.

I infer this is caused by the view state kept by JSF, but how to deal with this? Is there a way to implement it or do I have to stick to Ajax requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way to achieve this is to use Primefaces's Javascript API of

`PrimeFaces.widget.PickList`

Assuming your `widgetVar` is `pickListWV`, here's how you would do:

```
function transfer(string) {
        PF('pickListWV').sourceList.children().each(function() {
            var re = new RegExp(string, "i");
            if ($(this).attr('data-item-label').match(re)) {
                PF('pickListWV').selectItem($(this));// select the item
                PF('pickListWV').add();// add it to the target
            }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Also you can make it more interesting, like live filtering..

```
 <p:inputText
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { transfer(this.value); return false;} else{PF('pickListWV').filter(this.value, PF('pickListWV').sourceList)}" />
```

**EDIT 2:**

As I can see that you have a case-sensitive match, so you have to declare your RegExp as case-insensitive

```
var re = new RegExp(string, "i");
```

Here's a small working example on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/pickList/transfer.xhtml), and a working [demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/pickList/transfer.xhtml) as requested :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Hatem, thanks for your reply. Is the client side API for picklist available in 3.5.0? Haven't seen it in the docs :-(

Comment: The javascript api is not in the docs, not even in the 4.0 .. You can debug in the console and see the JS code and try to understand what it does.. To be honest I have tested your case with 4.0 and it worked fine.. And I think in the 3.5 it would work also

Comment: Tested with Mojarra 2.2.6 and PF 4.0 and does not work.. Can you post the whole test case that's working for you?

Comment: Seems nice my friend ;-) Will mark it as answered if getting working with 3.5

Comment: It works ;-) Personally, I don't like the idea of filtering the source list when key event happens as you do in your demo. But, omitting the `else` part, that does the work, in 3.5 too. Congrats!

Comment: After using the filter I would say yes me too I don't like the idea :) You're welcome my friend :)