# Primefaces picklist single click transfer

Tags: jsf, primefaces, picklist

Our users are so lazy.. what they want is whenever they select something on the picklist source it will be automatically transferred in the target list (and vice versa), so that they no longer need to click the Add/Remove button (w/c kinda make sense also). Any idea how to do this?

I'm thinking of using jquery but can't find any references. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will they be happy with drag-and-drop? Because it works out of the box and as far as I can see (PF5.0) double click works either.

Comment: Have a look to a question a made some time ago about [how to transfer items using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559619/building-a-client-side-transfer-method-for-ppicklist). Maybe it would be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onTargetSelectionChange or onSourceSelectionChange method to detect the selection. Then you can call setSource and setTarget method to update the state on both the side. Your transfer will be done on single click.